# How to locate 5 different choose file option having same xpath in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRe15.png)

I created my own xpath using the value as

```
.//*[@onclick='return clickFileUpload('openssme1')']
```

But it is not locating the choose file option individually.
Please help me to locate them individually so that i can choose 5 files.

Comment: Share the HTML code for the choose file option. `xpath` can not be same for 5 different nodes.

Comment: I have added the image which contains xpath of the same.

Comment: Can you share the *HTML* in *Text* format please. Problem can be easy to solve but only there is no sufficient info. users will just keep on guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to select a specific element and I know the position in the result generated by the xpath. Then you can simply append `[n]` to the end of the xpath, where n is the position number.

```
(//button[text()="Choose File"])[1]
```

Comment: Jason,i tried  //button[text()="Choose File"][1]  it is still selecting all 5 choose file option.. I'm stuck badly..

Comment: @KishanPatel - I've edited the xpath. This will surely work for you. :)

Comment: Jason - It is the same Xpath which i wrote. Unfortunately it is not working. you added Xpath : .//*[@onclick='return clickFileUpload('openssme1')'] which is same as what i uploaded.

Comment: @KishanPatel - Add parenthesis around the xpath and then provide the index value. Like this `(xpath)[n]`. That is the edit I've made.

Comment: Jason: Sorry for late reply. (//button[text()="Choose File"])[1] is working.. Thanks a lot.. Enjoying selenium. Will get back to you for further queries, if any.

Comment: @KishanPatel - Awesome! Do give it a green tick. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @KishanPatel - There is a tick below the downvote button of my answer. Check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Jason- Done.  Thank you again

Comment: Jason:All below mentioned things i know:
1) Finding element of drop down(select method)
2) Finding element of Simple text field
3) Finding element of Check box
4) Basic if, if else and other looping condition
5) Switching frames
6) Different methods to findelement i.e. by name, by tagname etc and then through xpath or css..

What more i need to learn ? Please Guide me...

Comment: :All below mentioned things i know:
1) Finding element of drop down(select method)
2) Finding element of Simple text field
3) Finding element of Check box
4) Basic if, if else and other looping condition
5) Switching frames
6) Different methods to findelement i.e. by name, by tagname etc and then through xpath or css..

What more i need to learn ? Please Guide me...

Answer (score 0):

You can select your element with other unique identifier. In your case, you can choose the number at the left of your button (the number)
Something like this :

```
//*[@id='uploaderList']/tr/td[contains(text(),'1')]/../td/button
```

Comment: .//*[@id='uploaderList']/tr[1]/td[2] i tried with this. It is not working

Comment: Yeah, but you try to use the button no ? If you tried with this xpath, you won't be able to click it. If you really want to use the brackets, which I don't recommend, try this : `.//*[@id='uploaderList']/tr[1]/td[2]/button`

Comment: : Yes that is the problem.. 
 
.//*[@id='uploaderList']/tr[1]/td[2] is working but i'm not able to click it. What should i do? I need to click that option in order to choose file. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to add `/button` at the end ?

Comment: Nicolas : (//button[text()="Choose File"])[1]  is working. Thank you for your help.. :-)